# How to dismiss dialog fragment after screen rotation (how to get the reference to the fragment)

Tags: android, fragment, dialogfragment

I'm showing a dialog fragment like `progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager());`

When my thread finishes, the dialog is dismissed. This is not working after screen rotation, because my 'progressDialog' variable is not set.

Using `progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "progressDialog");` and retaining the fragment manually would work, but this function is deprecated...

So what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [save instance state of your fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) or [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). After rotating your device you can obtain `Bundle` in [fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored%28android.os.Bundle%29) or [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

In this bundle you can store whatever you want from primitive types throug string arrays to `Serializable` and `Parcelable` object, so you can configure saved state as you wish.

If your `progressDialog` requires only visible state you can just store some flag like `isProgressBarShownig` in your instance state bundle.

Comment: that's what I usually do... Now I read, that `FragmentDialogs` are managed by their parent activities and they are at least displayed again after screen rotation... Now I can't dismiss this dialog anymore... only with the back button...

Comment: So maybe try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed() to dismiss dialog.

Comment: thanks for the halp, but I found the solution already... actually, the function meantioned in my question is NOT depraced... I'm using a library in which the wrapper was depraced... Not the function itself...